# How do I test for default route with angularjs + ui.router?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

In the gist https://gist.github.com/CarmineM74/10021667

You can see 2 files:

1. app.coffee
   contains states configuration
2. states.coffee
   The goal for this test is to check for correct fallback behaviour upon
   transition to an unexisting state.
   I thought that it was enough to force a transition via $sate.go(...) to
   an unexisting state and then check that $sate.current.name == 'home'

   When running tests I get:

   Error: Could not resolve 'really.unexisting.state' from state '' in ...

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more of research I found that, in order to make the test run I had to take into account the fact that $state.go(...) throws an exception when the state is not found.

Thus I had to wrap that call in a:

```
expect( ->
  $state.go('blah')
  $rootScope.$digest()
).toThrow()
```

That prevent the test to fail due to the exception that is thrown.

What's left is: how do I test for redirection to 'home' state?